# I want to show the filtered search from an array, I cannot return it in front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display the Project Name and other indexes from `filteredResults`, how can I map it and its indexes? Or parsing?

I put it on `onClick` event:

```js
function filter() {  
  var filteredResults = projectData.filter((f => f.ProjectName.includes(filterKeyword) && (f  => f.PartitionKey.includes(nameArea))));
  console.log(filteredResults);       
};

return:
  <Stack direction="row" id="projectResults">
    <Masonry columns={2} spacing={2}>
      {!!projectData && (
        projectData.map((card, index) => (
          <MasonryItem key={card.RowKey}>
            ...
          </MasonryItem>
        ))
      )}
    </Masonry>
  </Stack>
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input?

Comment: I will type a keyword for project name and dropdown for Area, and i will click a button to filter it and it will show the results from projectData.  i want to know how can i return the filteredResults like its mapping syntax

Answer (score 1):

Your filter `callback` is not valid.

Try changing it to this:

```
var filteredResults = projectData.filter(f => f.ProjectName.includes(filterKeyword) && f.PartitionKey.includes(nameArea));
```

Comment: it works that way too but i want to know the proper syntax like this,            
                    {!!projectData && (
                        projectData.map((card, index) => (

Comment: You may want to use [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to check if the value is truthy `projectData?.map((card, index) => {...})`

Comment: i put the value in filteredResults